# Detecting (non-)GNU Make when someone runs `make`

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a project whose makefile uses features exclusive to GNU Make. Sadly, there are platforms we must support where GNU make is still not the default when running `make`.

One of my colleagues was bitten by this, when a non-GNU make implementation silently failed to build our code correctly (it expanded an automatic variable to an empty string). I want to prevent that from happening again, by generating an explicit error message instead.

**What can I write in a `Makefile` to distinguish GNU make from non-GNU make, print a clear error, and exit?**

I've already figured out a workaround in renaming my real makefile to `GNUmakefile`, and putting a small stub in `Makefile`, but I'd rather something more direct.

The answers by Beta and Dan Moulding look really nice and simple, but on AIX 6.1, the make implementation can't handle either of them:

```
$ cat testmake

foo:
        touch foo

ifeq ($(shell $(MAKE) -v | grep GNU),)
$(error this is not GNU Make)
endif

ifeq "${MAKE_VERSION}" ""
$(info GNU Make not detected)
$(error ${MIN_MAKE_VER_MSG})
endif


$ /usr/bin/make -f testmake
"testmake", line 5: make: 1254-055 Dependency line needs colon or double colon operator.
"testmake", line 6: make: 1254-055 Dependency line needs colon or double colon operator.
"testmake", line 7: make: 1254-055 Dependency line needs colon or double colon operator.
"testmake", line 8: make: 1254-055 Dependency line needs colon or double colon operator.
"testmake", line 11: make: 1254-055 Dependency line needs colon or double colon operator.
"testmake", line 12: make: 1254-055 Dependency line needs colon or double colon operator.
"testmake", line 13: make: 1254-055 Dependency line needs colon or double colon operator.
make: 1254-058 Fatal errors encountered -- cannot continue.
```

I run into similar issues on both archaic and modern versions (Solaris 8 & 10) of Sun's make. That one's less critical, but would be nice to manage.

Comment: What version of GNU make are you running?

Comment: You are correct. The approach I had taken relied too heavily upon GNUisms, so may not work *at all* with non-GNU implementations of make. I am now doubting that there is a portable way to achieve your goal using just a Makefile (i.e. without resorting to a shell script or other external resource). I have rescinded my answer.

Answer (score 9):

As noted, GNU `make` checks for `GNUmakefile` before `makefile` or `Makefile`, I've used a trivial fix such as you described, a default (decoy) `Makefile` that causes an error/warning:

```
default:
    @echo "This requires GNU make, run gmake instead"
    exit 70
```

The GNU [make documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html) recommends using the `GNUmakefile` name when the `Makefile` is GNU make specific, so that's my preferred solution.

On platforms where the native `make` prefers a different Makefile name, you can do a variation on this, e.g. on FreeBSD I have the above decoy in the `BSDmakefile` which is used in preference to `Makefile` (thus preventing the system `make` from mangling my build). AFAICT the AIX or Solaris `make` do not have an alternate name you could use in this way.

One problem with a wrapper `Makefile` which tries to call GNU `make` is passing all the arguments.

A seemingly portable test (so far, I've found it to work on a mix of ancient OSF1, BSD and Solaris systems) you can use `SOMETHING=$(shell ...)` to detect if GNU `make` is running, non GNU versions will not set `SOMETHING`. Because of [deferred evaluation of variables](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/make.html#tag_04_84_13_04), you cannot use this as easily as might be expected though. This relies on the implementation silently handling macro names with spaces when expanded with `$()` (i.e. treats `$(shell foo)` as a variable/macro name rather than a [function](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Syntax-of-Functions), even though an assignment to such a name in that implementation would cause an error).

The only portable way you can print a *clear* error is to have a dummy target that is always run, using the above trick:

```
GNUMAKE=$(shell echo GNUMAKE)

default: gnumake all

gnumake:
        @[ "$(GNUMAKE)" = "GNUMAKE" ] || { echo GNU make required ; exit 70; }
```

This assumes you have a POSIX `sh` shell.

(I have seen tests which inspect `$(MAKE) -v` fail when both system and GNU make are called "`make`", the system `make` conspires against you and invokes GNU `make` ... You'd need some carefully checking of environment variables `PATH`, `MAKE` and possibly `SHELL` to handle every case.)

Comment: What about using `$(eval ...)` and `$(error ...)` somehow?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any internal feature that is definitely unique to GNUMake, but here's a kludge: call "make -v" and parse the output for "GNU" (since it seems unlikely that a non-GNU Make would have `MAKE` set to a GNU Make):

```
ifeq ($(shell $(MAKE) -v | grep GNU),)
$(error this is not GNU Make)
endif
```

**EDIT:**
Like Dan Moulding, I am starting to see the real size of this problem. As written, it requires a Makefile that is syntactically correct in **all** versions of Make. I don't have access to Sun Make (and I can't find manuals for it) so I don't know whether that's even possible, or how to write it if it is, or how to test it if I did.

But I can suggest an approach that might work. Maybe something like this can be made universal:

```
default:
  ./runGNUMake.pl
```

That's it, that's the whole makefile. Then write the `runGNUMake` script in Perl (or bash, or whatever you like) that will do something like my "make -v" kludge and then either print the error message or run "make -f realMakefile".

Comment: I had thought of doing this in an external script that ran before make, but I hadn't thought of embedding it in the makefile itself.

Comment: Novelocrat: really? How does it fail, does a non-GNU Make have a `MAKE` that appears to be set to a GNU Make, or does a GNU Make appear to be non-GNU? ( I guess we could call those "false positive" and "false negative" respectively.)

Comment: I edited the question to show the failure. It doesn't like `ifeq`.